# Making clickable links for mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, click

i need some help with this i have tried making the links clickable in

```
echo "<p><a href="https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$results['lowid']."<h3>".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['lowql']."<h3>".$results['profession']."
```

";
but i haven't had any luck it works before i try to add the hyperlinks i'm not sure what i am doing wrong.

this is the original code

```
echo "<p><h3>".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['lowql']."<h3>".$results['profession']."</p>";
```

That code works like a charm but i want to make every item that is displayed clickable. but when i edit the code it breaks altogether.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Search</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="results">
```

and here is the php code

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query'];
// gets value sent over search form

$min_length = 0;
// you can set minimum length of the query if you want

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM nanos
        WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`lowql` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`profession` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`lowid` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    // * means that it selects all fields, you can also write: `id`, `title`, `text`
    // articles is the name of our table

    // '%$query%' is what we're looking for, % means anything, for example if $query is Hello
    // it will match "hello", "Hello man", "gogohello", if you want exact match use `title`='$query'
    // or if you want to match just full word so "gogohello" is out use '% $query %' ...OR ... '$query %' ... OR ... '% $query'

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
        // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

            echo "<p><a href="https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$results['lowid']."<h3>".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['lowql']."<h3>".$results['profession']."</p>";
            // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
        }
    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
```

Comment: You want to include `h3` tag into `a` tag???

Comment: I want the results to be clickable with the outside link that is in the code already. it will pull the results and display them on the search.php page but i also want them clickable so they go to the outside like as well.

Comment: But why is there a need of `h3` tag? You want to style url variables???

Comment: `echo "<p><a href="https: ...`, incorrect punctuation of quotes, that's why the links are not clickable.

Comment: Well no i want it however it will work if there is a way to make it work with the <a href attribute than that's the way i want to go i want the results displayed on the search.php page which they are before i try editing the code. but when i try to add in the <a href variable it breaks and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the `a` is to redirect the page with `url variables/parameters` then this will do the work:

```
<?php 

  $lowid = 1;
  $name = 2;
  $lowql = 3;
  $prof = 4;

  echo "<a href=https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$lowid."&name=".$name."&lowql=".$lowql."&prof=".$prof.">Click Me</a>";

?>
```

You just need to get the values using `$_GET['variable_name']` from `search.php`.

I don't see the need of `h3` in `url`.

Comment: echo "<p><h3><a href='https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$results['lowid']."'<a>".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['lowql']."<h3>".$results['profession']."</p>"; it goes to the external website but the lowid isn't specified but i can pull up the search using the lowid number

Comment: @Adventchaos Try this:

`echo "<p><h3><a href=https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$lowid."&name=".$name."&lowql=".$lowql."&prof=".$prof.">Click Me</a></h3></p>";`

Comment: there is a list of over 1000 items that need to lead to external links i query the databse and it returns the way it is supposed to once i change the code with different puncuation it makes it clickable and it leads to the correct external site but the id that is supposed to be after db.php?id= isn't there

Comment: Then show here the code that generates the url that is correct but is without id.

Comment: this is the link to the page that it generates with the clickable link http://www.circleofnotum.com/con/search.php?query= this is the code that generates that page `echo "<p><h3><a href='https://www.auno.org/ao/db.php?id=".$results['lowid']."'<a>'".$results['name']."</h3>".$results['lowql']."<h3>".$results['profession']."</p>";`

Comment: Can you please explain to me clearly why you are adding another `<a>` tag inside an `<a>` tag with also `<h3>` tags inside??? Is this your first time doing that?

Comment: That's how i was told to do it in the beginning.

Comment: You got it to work before? Or have you done it before??

Comment: no i haven't done this particular thing before but the way the code is now it will display the content and they are clicable but when i click the link it takes me to the page without the id number on it

Comment: Seeing your coding style and your answers, I prefer that you should study more about what you are doing instead of doing it right away without proper knowledge about this and that. Good luck.

PS: `mysql_*` is already deprecated, use `mysqli_*` instead.